# get the total number of div using selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Below is the HTML page

```
<div class="box">
            <div class="box3 disbox"></div>

            <div class="box3 top"><input type="hidden" value="38206" name="jdh0"> 
                <div class="box3-1 bg1">1</div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box3 top"><input type="hidden" value="38215" name="jdh1"> 
                <div class="box3-1 bg1">2</div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box3 top"><input type="hidden" value="38214" name="jdh2"> 
                <div class="box3-1 bg1">3</div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box3 top"><input type="hidden" value="38216" name="jdh3"> 
                <div class="box3-1 bg1">4</div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want the total number of div count which is equal to `<div class="box3 top">` from the `<div class="box">`

I tried with below code, but its count all the div irrespective of class, let me know how can I count the div based on the class name?

```
WebElement resultGrid = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]"))
            List<WebElement>totalRow = resultGrid.findElements(By.tagName("div"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count and print the total number of `<div class="box3 top">` within `<div class="box">` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.box div.box3.top"))).size());
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='box']//div[@class='box3 top']"))).size());
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is my expectation